# Memory drop when using CTAS in postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-9.6

I am using Postgres version 9.6. I have postgis extension installed and I am trying to do `create table as select distinct ...` and during the query execution, memory usage is very high. I have work_mem set to 100 MB.

I am new to Postgres and I would like to understand how CTAS works in Postgres. My understanding is that it creates a new table structure and copies the data based on select. When CTAS is used, it makes use of work_mem and when work_mem is not sufficient, it spills over to the disk.

Is this why the memory is dropping? Or could this be a memory leak? Looking for some help.

Comment: Well, a DISTINCT on a large result set is going to use memory, but that memory will be released as soon as the query finishes (or at least when you close the connection that ran the statement). I am not really sure what your question is. If you don't have enough memory, to support a work_mem of 100MB, then don't use such a large number for it. Remember: a single query can allocate work_mem multiple times!

Comment: Is the CTAS memory usage much different than just running the plain SELECT query with EXPLAIN ANALYZE?